# Shell script to validate if my tomcat is running or not - uniquely identify

Tags: java, shell, tomcat, unique, alfresco

I see many shell scripts to check process if that is running we proceed further.

But there is scenario like below or if we have multiple tomcat running on single host, how do we identify if our process running?
e.g  if I go to path /opt/alfresco/tomcat/bin   and execute command

> ps -ef | grep tomcat

It will give me output (even tomcat is not running)

```
[alfresco@host030 bin]$ ps -ef |grep tomcat
alfresco 12090 11302  0 22:57 pts/0    00:00:00 grep tomcat
[alfresco@host030 bin]$
```

So if I am using alfresco tomcat and I need to validate if my tomcat process actually started and running, how do I validate?

Also to differentiate between any java and tomcat running,  HOW ?

Comment: do you want to check if the tomcat running or if the webapp is running?

Comment: As per your ps -ef output, it shows no process of tomcat is currently running. The process you are seeing is the grep command you use to fetch tomcat.

Comment: Yes that is what I want to differentiate my tomcat uniquely to validate that my tomcat is running or not. Any way to get identify

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the below script. Do grep for the listening port, use your **port number**.

```
 JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
 SHUTDOWN_PORT=`netstat -vatn|grep LISTEN|grep 8005|wc -l`
 export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
 if [ $SHUTDOWN_PORT -ne 0 ]; then
 echo 'Alfresco is running'
 else
 echo "Alfresco is  not running"
```

To start it you can use

```
ALF_HOME=/www/web/dev1/alfresco
$ALF_SCRIPT start
```

Comment: Not getting idea behind checking shutdown port for this. can you explain plz?

Comment: Also what happen if multiple tomcat instance running on single host?

Comment: Ports are configured in the tomcat/conf/server.xml file.
Tomcat listens to at least two network ports, one for the shutdown command, and one or more for accepting requests. Two instances of Tomcat can’t listen to the same port number on the same Host/ IP address, so you will need to edit your server.xml files to change the ports they listen to.

Answer (score 0):

If your tomcat is running as a service you can run `service tomcat status`.
If its not running as service its recommended to do it..

Read this how to do it: https://www.linux.com/learn/managing-linux-daemons-init-scripts

Comment: No Tomcat is not running with service... it is manual...  via    alfresco.sh start command